# Passing a datarow to a form and binding the controls to it

Tags: c#, data-binding, crud, datarow

Many hours of internet searching has revealed no definitive answer on this question, so I thought I would re-hash it.  I need to pass a datarow to a form then bind the controls in that form to the values in the datarow.  The Datarow was created by a class method:

```
DataRow newRow = cusData.PrimeRecord();
newRow["recordid"] = cusData.GetRecordID();
newRow["recdate"] = DateTime.Now;
newRow["lastmod"] = DateTime.Now;
CusUpdate updateFrm = new CusUpdate(newRow);
```

where the PrimeRecord() method is defined with the following code:

```
public DataRow PrimeRecord(){    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" LIMIT 1",sqlConnect);
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.FillSchema(dt,SchemaType.Mapped);
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    return dr;
}
```

All my Database CRUD code has already been defined and I don't want to bind to DataAdapters, etc.  I simply want to pass the DataRow to a form, update the data then pass it to it's proper CRUD method. I will take any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the data binding features of `Windows Forms`. Unfortunately, you can't use the `DataRow` object directly (see the Remarks section of this [`ctor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wkkxwcz.aspx) of the `Binding` class). Use the table / view instead, inside the form:

```
DataView dv = row.Table.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "recordid=" + row["recordid"].ToString();
dtpRecDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", dv, "recdate");
dtpLastMod.DataBindings.Add("Value", dv, "lastmod");
```

where `row` is the `DataRow` object passed to the form constructor and `dtpRecDate` and `dtpLastMod` are [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) controls.

Comment: Dan, that did EXACTLY what I needed.  Thanks for all your help!